# Change youtube video on image on stop state

Tags: javascript, video, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I made the code like this which changes an image on the web-site on Youtube video.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(window).load(function(){
    $('img.demovideo').click(function(){
        video = '<iframe class="demovideo" width="100%" height="551px" src="'+ $(this).attr('data-video') +'"></iframe>';
    $(this).replaceWith(video);
});
$('img.demovideo').css('cursor', 'pointer');
});
</script>
```

How can I change the Youtube video back on image on player state 0?

I made a code like this, but it doesn't work:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

raketaplayer.onStateChange () {

b = raketaplayer.getPlayerState();

if (b=0) {

image = '<img class="demovideo" src="http://raketa.pro/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/image_header_2.png" data-video="http://www.youtube.com/embed/7hoqO36CVRM?&amp;rel=0&amp;theme=light&amp;showinfo=0&amp;hd=1&amp;autohide=1&amp;color=white&amp;autoplay=1&amp;enablejsapi=1&amp;playerapiid=raketaplayer" style="cursor: pointer;">';
    $(iframe.demovideo).replaceWith(image);
});
$('img.demovideo').css('cursor', 'pointer');
});

}

}

</script>
```

What's wrong with it? Please, help :)

Image code as follows:

```
<img class="demovideo" src="http://raketa.pro/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/image_header.png" data-video="http://www.youtube.com/embed/7hoqO36CVRM?&rel=0&theme=light&showinfo=0&hd=1&autohide=1&color=white&autoplay=1&amp;enablejsapi=1&amp;playerapiid=raketaplayer">
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of issues that you might want to address. First of all, your conditional statement uses a single equal sign instead of a double. More importantly, though, when you execute the onStateChange function, it can take an argument that represents the event, which will report the state change without you having to query for it, like this:

```
raketaplayer.onStateChange (event) {

if (event.data==0) {

image = '<img class="demovideo" src="http://raketa.pro/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/image_header_2.png" data-video="http://www.youtube.com/embed/7hoqO36CVRM?&amp;rel=0&amp;theme=light&amp;showinfo=0&amp;hd=1&amp;autohide=1&amp;color=white&amp;autoplay=1&amp;enablejsapi=1&amp;playerapiid=raketaplayer" style="cursor: pointer;">';
    $(iframe.demovideo).replaceWith(image);
});
$('img.demovideo').css('cursor', 'pointer');
});

}

}
```

Finally, make sure you've bound your onStateChange function to the state change event of the YT.Player object that you create elsewhere in your code.

Comment: how can I bound and event? i am using iframe. and onStateChange is an api of youtube player, i thought that onStateChange listens the raketaplayer state and when it equals 0, script is executing.

Comment: While the iframe will raise the state change events, you don't have any way of listening to them (it isn't automatic). You'll need to include the iFrame API before defining your $(window).load function, and then within the click function (after the iframe is created) you can set up a YT.Player object that can be bound to the events. See here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Getting_Started for more details.

Comment: can you help with code please? i can't understand how to link all this things together... (((